# addClass in javascript not work in php codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I need to active the navigation when click in it. And I used javascript to active the navigation.My code is as below:

```
<?php 
    $uri = $this->uri->segment(0);
    $uri1 = $this->uri->segment(1);
    if ($uri=='') {
?>          
     <script type="text/javascript">
        //make a class toActive in whick active to be added on body load
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.navHome').addClass('active');
        });
    </script>
<?php
    }       
?>

<?php if ($uri1 == 'company_profile') { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //make a class toActive in whick active to be added on body load
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.navCompany').addClass('active');
        });
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

My navigation code is:-

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                 <li class="navHome"><a href="<?php echo site_url()?>">HOME</a></li>
                <li  class="navCompany"><a href="<?php echo site_url()?>company_profile">COMPANY PROFILE</a></li>
<ul>
```

Comment: can you show  where you included jQuery script?

Comment: What are you getting within `uri` and `uri1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things.

Close the `<ul>` tag.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                 <li class="navHome"><a href="<?php echo site_url()?>">HOME</a></li>
                <li  class="navCompany"><a href="<?php echo site_url()?>company_profile">COMPANY PROFILE</a></li>
<ul>
```

When using php inside your HTML markup, it is best to leave one space after `<?php`and one space before`?>` as sometimes it throws error. Also, close your statements.
Change:

```
<?php echo site_url()?>
```

To:

```
<?php echo site_url(); ?>
```

As for trying to do your "active" task, why not do it during creationg of your page, not after with JS?

At the top of the page set your variables

```
<?php 
    $uri = $this->uri->segment(0);
    $uri1 = $this->uri->segment(1);
?>
```

And then at your `<li>` add the "`active`" class based on the variables.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="navHome <?php if($uri=='') echo 'active'; ?>" ><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>">HOME</a></li>
    <li  class="navCompany <?php if($uri1=='company_profile') echo 'active'; ?>"n><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>company_profile">COMPANY PROFILE</a></li>
</ul>
```

That way there is no need for jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

here i explain you how we store php variable in javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var uri1 = '<?php echo $this->uri->segment(1); ?>';//store your uri segment her
        if (uri1 != "") {
            //make a class toActive in whick active to be added on body load    
            $('.navHome').addClass('active');
        }
        if (uri1 == 'company_profile') {
            //make a class toActive in whick active to be added on body load
            $('.navCompany').addClass('active');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This code also not active my navigation one menu at a time.